# Sorting columnGroup header values in jasper crosstab

Tags: sorting, jasper-reports, pivot-table

I have a issue with sorting of columnGroup in crosstab as values are sorted in alphabetical order, for example:

1. Question one | 10. Question ten | 11. Some question | 2. Question two ...

However i am trying to get following result - sorted as numbers:

1. Question one | 2. Question two | 10. Question ten | 11. Some question

I defined this measure

```
<measure name="questionSort" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <measureExpression><![CDATA[java.lang.Integer.parseInt(new 
      java.lang.String($F{questionString}).substring(0,new java.lang.String($F{questionString}).indexOf("."))) + 0]]>
    </measureExpression>
</measure>
```

And then i tried to use orderByExpression in columnGroup like this:

```
<columnGroup name="question" height="105">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{question}]]></bucketExpression>
                        <orderByExpression><![CDATA[($V{questionSort} == null ? 100 : $V{questionSort})]]></orderByExpression>
                    </bucket>
 ...
</columnGroup>
```

However columnGroup is still sorted in alphabetical order..

What am i doing wrong here, any help will be appreciated.